# ServiceStack: Accessing the HttpRequest in a selfhosted application

Tags: session, authentication, servicestack

I currently have an IIS hosted application that I would like to switch over to use the self-hosted method.

But I'm having difficulty accessing the session so I can retrieve the current users username.

This is the code I used when hosting under IIS which worked perfectly:

```
/// <summary>
/// A basic wrapper for the service stack session, to allow access to it lower down in the DAL layer without tying us to servicestack.
/// </summary>
public class ServiceStackAuthTokenService : IAuthTokenService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// GetCurrentAuthToken.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A string representing the users auth name.</returns>
    public string GetCurrentAuthToken()
    {
        // Grab the current request.
        var req = HttpContext.Current.Request.ToRequest();
        var res = HttpContext.Current.Response.ToResponse();

        // Fetch the authentication service.
        var authService = EndpointHost.AppHost.TryResolve<AuthService>();
        authService.RequestContext = new HttpRequestContext(req, res, null);

        // Grab the session.
        var session = authService.GetSession(false);

        // Return the username.
        return session.UserName;
    }

    public string UserPropertyName
    {
        get { return "UserName"; }
    }
}
```

This is added to the app host with the following code::

```
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<ServiceStackAuthTokenService, IAuthTokenService>()
```

When running self-hosted the HttpContext.Current is null, how do I access the request under a self-hosted application?

Thanks!

**Update**
Additional things I have tried:

as per an post here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/servicestack/jnX8UwRWN8A/_XWzTGbnuHgJ

It was suggested to use:

container.Register>(c => AuthService.CurrentSessionFactory);

This just returns a newed IAuthSession.

What the user in that post is doing is exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

In the last post Mythz says:

Just to be clear, in order to form the Session Key that references the Users session you need either the ss-id or ss-pid cookies (as determined by ss-opts).
You can get cookies off the IHttpRequest object or otherwise in ASP.NET the HttpContext.Current.Request singleton, so whatever IAuthUserSession factory you inject needs to take something that can give it the cookies, i.e. either an IRequestContext, IHttpRequest, IService, etc.

But I still cant see a way to access the IHttpRequest.

Comment: When/Where does GetCurrentAuthToken() get called in your application? If it's in a Service you could pass IHttpRequest and IHttpResponse into the method like GetCurrentAuthToken(base.Request, base.Response).

Comment: Hi Paaschpa, It occurs in the DAL layer which has no direct relationship back to the service layer. I could pass the context into the DALs but that would violate the design and keep each layer separate.

Comment: Having look into this further, I can see the IHttpRequest and the IHttpResponse is being injected into service via the IRequiresRequestContext interface that is in the service base class.

I basically want to be able to access the same thing so I can get access to the cache where the client session is stored.

Comment: using reflector looking at the service class I can see that

  if (this.userSession == null)
  {
   this.userSession = this.TryResolve<TUserSession>();
   if (this.userSession == null)
   {
    this.userSession = this.Cache.SessionAs(this.Request,   this.Response);
   }
  }
  return (TUserSession)((object)this.userSession);

This code seems to suggest, that the session is accessible via the cache.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For ServiceStack 3, you can share request data via the `HostContext.Instance.Items` Dictionary. For ServiceStack 4, you should use the `HostContext.RequestContext.Items` Dictionary.

For example, add a request filter in your app host configuration to save the value:

```
// Put the session into the hostcontext.
RequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) =>
{
  HostContext.Instance.Items.Add("Session", req.GetSession());
});
```

Then in your authentication token class pull it back out:

```
public string GetCurrentAuthToken()
{
  var session = HostContext.Instance.Items["Session"] as AuthUserSession;

   if (session != null)
   {
     return session.UserName;
   }

   throw new Exception("No attached session found.");
}
```

Comment: Is HostContext.Instance really per request?

Comment: From what I can tell it does appears to be. Upon every request it appears to be empty and no information from the previous calls are persisted.

In the servictstack source there is this in (AppHostBase.cs), which suggests to me it is emptied on each request.

    public virtual void OnEndRequest()
    {
       foreach (var item in HostContext.Instance.Items.Values)
       {
          Release(item);
       }

       HostContext.Instance.EndRequest();
    }

 But like all things perhaps give it a try and see if works for you.

Comment: so how do you save things back into the session?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I was hoping Mythz would chime in on this and give us some additional information. I haven't worked on this for a while as I have been busy, but if I do come across and answer I will provide further information.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but people seem to be down voting it. That suggests to me they know a better way or this isn't correct. If that is the case I'd love to hear what the correct way of going is, or why the down votes.

Comment: @Rtype I didn't downvote but this solution doesn't work with Self-Hosted ServiceStack because requests can be split up over several threads and the Context isn't shared between them. I'm having to pass the data up from the service layer where Request.Items is shared between threads.

Comment: @carlin.scott thank you for the reply! Interesting. We have since moved away from using service stack, since they switched to the paid product. So we don't use this anymore. Perhaps it is worth posting your solution to help people?