# How do I inject ServiceStack AuthSession into my repository classes?

Tags: servicestack

I am struggling to find the correct way to inject the current instance of a `UserAuthSession` object (derived from ServiceStack's `AuthUserSession`) into my data-access repositories in order for them to automatically update change tracking fields on insert/update/delete operations.

If I were newing-up repositories in my service code it would be a no-brainer, I would just do:

```
var repo = new MyRepository(SessionAs<UserAuthSession>());
```

However, my repositories are auto-wired (injected) into the services, so the `UserAuthSession` has to be grabbed from somewhere in the lambda defined for the repository's registration with the IOC container, e.g.:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        container.Register<IRepository>(c =>
        {
            return new MyRepository(**?????**);  <-- resolve and pass UserAuthSession
        }
    }
}
```

Now, looking at the ServiceStack code for the `Service` class:

```
    private object userSession;
    protected virtual TUserSession SessionAs<TUserSession>()
    {
        if (userSession == null)
        {
            userSession = TryResolve<TUserSession>(); //Easier to mock
            if (userSession == null)
                userSession = Cache.SessionAs<TUserSession>(Request, Response);
        }
        return (TUserSession)userSession;
    }
```

I can see that it looks up the cached session based on the current `Request` and `Response`, but those are not available to me in the lambda.

What's the solution? Or am I approaching the problem from an entirely wrong angle?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am testing my code using a `JsonServiceClient`, NOT by calling service methods directly. So I was expecting `HttpContext.Current` to be available in the lambda, but it is always null.

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer in [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802182/servicestack-accessing-the-httprequest-in-a-selfhosted-application) that stores the session built from the request in the request/thread-scoped `Items` dictionary of `ServiceStack.Common.HostContext`. .

My `AppHost.Configure()` now has the following code:

```
// Add a request filter storing the current session in HostContext to be
// accessible from anywhere within the scope of the current request.
RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes, requestDTO) =>
{
    var session = httpReq.GetSession();
    HostContext.Instance.Items.Add(Constants.UserSessionKey, session);
});

// Make UserAuthSession resolvable from HostContext.Instance.Items.
container.Register<UserAuthSession>(c =>
{
    return HostContext.Instance.Items[Constants.UserSessionKey] as UserAuthSession;
});

// Wire up the repository.
container.Register<IRepository>(c => 
{ 
    return new MyRepository(c.Resolve<UserAuthSession>()); 
});
```

Comment: great but how do you save things back into the session?

Comment: I don't care about saving anything back to the session, in my case this is a one-way street only when my repos need to know the identity of the user that's about to modify the data.